# bind property of object to datagridview to be DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to bind a property of object to datagridview to be DataGridViewComboBoxColumn so that user select specific values only .
autogenerated must to be true as I will use it for multiple objects .

I tried to catch column and change it to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn but it has getter only no setter.

this is a sample of what I want .

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<GridClass> BindLxxxist = new List<GridClass>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            GridClass g = new GridClass(i.ToString());
            BindLxxxist.Add(g);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<GridClass>(BindLxxxist);
        List<string> idsList=new   List<string>() {"id1","id12"};
        //how to make id column appears as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to make user select from idsList only.
    }

}
public class GridClass
{
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [ListBindable(BindableSupport.Yes)]

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }



    public GridClass(string val)
    {
        Id = val;
        FirstName = "FirstName" + val;
        LastName = "LastName" + val;


    }


}
```

Comment: You can build a custom `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` class object an give it the properties you need. Your custom column will have its own [DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2))

Comment: but in this way I will have to create each column in my datagridview .

Comment: my question is how to make Id property be binded to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn  when I bind Lis<GridClass
> to datagridview ?